# Getting an Error when inserting xmlfile to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, sqlxml

I'm trying to insert a xml file that I read from a stream into a column of type xml in mssql server
like this:

//read file from stream

```
                    var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    var string = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

//convert to xmldoc

```
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.LoadXml(string);
```

//Try to inser it into the table using the xmlDoc

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                @"INSERT INTO [XMLTable] (XmlData) VALUES(@XmlData);", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XmlData", xmlDoc.InnerXml);

                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
             
            }
        }
```

//Sample xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ChangeSSNR version="1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.testschema.com/ChangeSSNR/1.0/">
  <Header version="1.0">
    <From>someone</From>
    <To>someoneelse</To>
    <TimeStamp>1900-01-01T01:01:01+01:00</TimeStamp>
    <ppnSchema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
  </Header>
  <ChangeSSNRid id="4294967295">
    <SSNRChange>
      <NewSSNR>09834098098</NewSSNR>
      <OldSSNR>9879879827345</OldSSNR>
    </SSNRChange>
  </ChangeSSNRid>
  <ChangeSSNRid id="42949367295">
    <SSNRChange>
      <NewSSNR>098340980983</NewSSNR>
      <OldSSNR>98798798273453</OldSSNR>
    </SSNRChange>
  </ChangeSSNRid>
</ChangeSSNR>
```

Getting an exception : XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding

Kind Regards

/Rudy

Comment: Please update your question, and add a sample of the XML. My bet is that it has XML prolog declaration with 'bad' encoding for SQL Server.

Comment: Also, the code snippet `xmlDoc.LoadXml(inläst);` is using unknown variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML file shouldn't have any leading spaces on the first line:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ChangeSSNR version="1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.testschema.com/ChangeSSNR/1.0/">
    <Header version="1.0">
        <From>someone</From>
        <To>someoneelse</To>
        <TimeStamp>1900-01-01T01:01:01+01:00</TimeStamp>
        <ppnSchema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:nil="true"/>
    </Header>
    <ChangeSSNRid id="4294967295">
        <SSNRChange>
            <NewSSNR>09834098098</NewSSNR>
            <OldSSNR>9879879827345</OldSSNR>
        </SSNRChange>
    </ChangeSSNRid>
    <ChangeSSNRid id="42949367295">
        <SSNRChange>
            <NewSSNR>098340980983</NewSSNR>
            <OldSSNR>98798798273453</OldSSNR>
        </SSNRChange>
    </ChangeSSNRid>
</ChangeSSNR>
```

It is better to use LINQ to XML while dealing with XML. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

**c#**

```
...
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(string);
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XmlData", xdoc.ToString());
```

Comment: Using XDocument made it work!

Thanks Yitzhak Khabinsky.

Comment: @RudyW, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.